# how to pass the javascript variable in to php in same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, excel

How can i assign the javascript variable in to php.

```
$("button").click(function() {

        var val = (this.id);

$.ajax ({
            url: "date.php",
            //data: { val : val },
            data:'q=' + val,
            type: "GET",
            success: function(result) {

             if(result==1)
             {
            page = "<?php echo $today;?>";
             }
            else if(result==2)
            {
            page = "<?php echo $this_week;?>";
            }
            else if(result==3)
            {
            page="<?php echo $this_month;?>";
            }   
            else if(result==4)
            {
            page="<?php echo $previous_month;?>";
            }   
            else
            {
            "<?php echo $today;?>";
            }   
           }
        });
    });
```

Here i want to pass the variable 'page' to  php,for to assign the export excel filename.I done like this in php

```
<?php
$page = ('<script type="text/javascript">page</script>');
?>
```

$page variable i want to assign here.

```
<script>
    saveAs(new Blob([s2ab(wbout)],{type:"application/octet-stream"}), "<?php echo $name[0] ?>- Report-<?php echo $page?>.xlsx");
    };
</script>
```

But am getting error,otherwise any other method to assign the variable.

my date.php

```
<?php
    $var=$_GET['q'];
    if($var == 'getToday')
    {
        echo "1";
    }
    elseif($var =='getWeek')
    {
      echo "2";
    }
    else if($var =='getMonth')
    {
      echo "3";
    }
    else if($var =='getpremon')
    {
      echo "4";
    }
    else
    {
      echo "5";
    }
?>
```

Comment: use ajax to send jQuery variable values . So in backend PHP file it will be set

Comment: Why are you mixing PHP and JavaScript at all here?  If you're just calculating a date, both languages are fully capable of doing that.  You don't need to use JavaScript to ask PHP what the date is just to tell PHP what that date was.  What are you *actually* trying to accomplish here?

Comment: i just wanted to get the variable for assigning the excel filename

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the java script variable "page",

```
<script>
saveAs(new Blob([s2ab(wbout)],{type:"application/octet-stream"}), "<?php echo $name[0] ?>-       BI Usage Report-"+page+".xlsx");
};
```

Don't need to mix java script variable to php.

else you can return values directly from mydate.php,See the code below

```
<?php 
$var=$_GET['q'];


    if($var == 'getToday')
        {
         echo $today;
        }
    elseif($var =='getWeek')
        {
          echo $this_week;
        }
    else if($var =='getMonth')
        {
           echo $this_month;
        }
    else if($var =='getpremon')
        {
          echo $previous_month;
        }
    else
        {
          echo "5";
        }

 ?>
```

And
     $("button").click(function() {

```
    var val = (this.id);

     $.ajax ({
        url: "date.php",
        //data: { val : val },
        data:'q=' + val,
        type: "GET",
        success: function(result) {
          page = result
         }
    });
});
```

Now you can use java script variable "page".

Answer (score 0):

Basically you cannot run the client script or assign values to the server script but to achieve our goal we can use the `ajax` to assign the `jquery variable` to `php`

```
$.ajax ({
        url: "date.php",
        //data: { val : val },
        data:'q=' + val,
        type: "GET",
        success: function(result) {

         if(result==1)
         {
        page = "<?php echo $today;?>";
         }
        else if(result==2)
        {
        page = "<?php echo $this_week;?>";
        }
        else if(result==3)
        {
        page="<?php echo $this_month;?>";
        }   
        else if(result==4)
        {
        page="<?php echo $previous_month;?>";
        }   
        else
        {
        "<?php echo $today;?>";
        }
       $.ajax({
           url:'url',
           type:'GET/POST',
           data:{page:page} <-----This send the value from js to php 

           })   
       }
    });
});
```

here `URL` is the location where you want to get the `variable page` value